# how to manipulate data in Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, datatables

I am using Datatables with Vue.js to render content in the form of tables. here is my code:

```
computed: {
    job_table: function () {
      return {
        title: this.$t('commons.users'),
        headers:[
          {
            text: "Post",
            value : "title",
            align: "left",
            filter: 'capitalize',
            search : 'title'
          },
          {
            text: "New Application",
            value : "applications",
            align: "left",
            filter: 'capitalize',
            search : 'applications'
          },
          {
            text: "Status",
            value : "status",
            align: "left", 
            filter: 'capitalize',
            search : 'status'
          },
          {
            text: "Posted On",
            value : "created_at",
            align: "left",
            filter: 'capitalize',
            search : ''
          },
          {
            text: "Actions",
            align: "left",
            value : "role",
            filter: 'roleFilter',
            search : false
          }
        ],
        desc: 'created_at',
        resource: 'job',
        w:'company',
        actions: {
          add: "AddEmployee",
          edit: "EditEmployee"
        },
        params:{
          company_id: true
        }
      }
    },
  }
```

I wanted to change the format of "created at" and take a count of "applications" which is an array. can I make callback on them.

```
 {
            text: "New Application",
            value : "applications",
            align: "left",
            filter: 'capitalize',
            search : 'applications'
          }, 
{
            text: "Posted On",
            value : "created_at",
            align: "left",
            filter: 'capitalize',
            search : ''
          },
```

I am new in JavaScript and any help would be highly appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which datatable you would like to use (Bootstrap, Vuetify etc.) but for applications, you can try this:

```
{
            text: "New Application",
            value : "applications.length",
            align: "left",
            filter: 'capitalize',
            search : 'applications'
          },
```

So the value will be the length of the applications array.

Formatting the `created_at` you should look after is there a way to use slots for the Datatable, usually libraries use slots and templates to inject custom formatting. For example for Vuetify: https://dev.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#slots

Comment: I want length based on application statuses, so is there a way to count length of applications having statuses new, passed etc